# For loop with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, imagemagick

I'm new to working with images, and i'm trying to resize files en masse.

| filename | format | width | height | colorspace | matte | filesize | density | Megapixels | maxparam | factor | new height | new width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KEK1222AER_1.jpg | JPEG | 4637 | 6494 | sRGB | FALSE | 2293580 | 96x96 | 30.112678 | 6494 | 0.315676009 | 20571.72488 | 14689.11122 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KEK1222AOB_1.png | PNG | 4651 | 6525 | sRGB | TRUE | 10801085 | 118x118 | 30.347775 | 6525 | 0.314176245 | 20768.59756 | 14803.79268 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KEK1222ASX_1.jpg | JPEG | 4601 | 6503 | sRGB | FALSE | 2556722 | 96x96 | 29.920303 | 6503 | 0.31523912 | 20628.78488 | 14595.26976 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KEK1222AWH_1.jpg | JPEG | 4637 | 6494 | sRGB | FALSE | 1504188 | 300x300 | 30.112678 | 6494 | 0.315676009 | 20571.72488 | 14689.11122 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFC3516AAC_1.jpg | TIFF | 4296 | 5526 | sRGB | TRUE | 43705164 | 300x300 | 23.739696 | 5526 | 0.370973579 | 14895.93951 | 11580.33951 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFC3516ACU_1.jpg | TIFF | 4296 | 5526 | sRGB | TRUE | 46561548 | 300x300 | 23.739696 | 5526 | 0.370973579 | 14895.93951 | 11580.33951 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFC3516AER_1.jpg | TIFF | 4296 | 5526 | sRGB | TRUE | 44582636 | 300x300 | 23.739696 | 5526 | 0.370973579 | 14895.93951 | 11580.33951 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFC3516AOB_1.jpg | TIFF | 4296 | 5526 | sRGB | TRUE | 41562732 | 300x300 | 23.739696 | 5526 | 0.370973579 | 14895.93951 | 11580.33951 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFP0719AAC_1.jpg | TIFF | 4381 | 6269 | sRGB | FALSE | 122123560 | 300x300 | 27.464489 | 6269 | 0.327005902 | 19170.9078 | 13397.31171 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KFP0919AAC_1.jpg | TIFF | 4381 | 6269 | sRGB | FALSE | 125133076 | 300x300 | 27.464489 | 6269 | 0.327005902 | 19170.9078 | 13397.31171 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027AAC_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 4705371 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027ACU_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 4848262 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027ADR_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 1378979 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027AER_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 4822582 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027AOB_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 4916966 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027APT_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 1397586 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |
| C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA/KA - 5KSB4027AVB_1.jpg | JPEG | 4096 | 5456 | sRGB | FALSE | 4743516 | 300x300 | 22.347776 | 5456 | 0.375733138 | 14520.94439 | 10901.35415 |

This table represents all images downloaded from an S3 bucket which exceeds the megapixel limit for a website. I am hoping to sequence along "filename" and read the image, then resize it by a factor of "factor". My attempted code was as follows:

```
for (i in seq_along(calculator$filename)){function(x) image_read(x)%>%image_resize(., "factor" )%>%image_write(.,paste(x))}
```

The only output I get is 'i' as an integer of length 17.

I feel like i'm missing some kind of object creation and have some incorrect syntax. Can anybody fix my code?

Comment: What you are essentially doing here is that you are "defining" a function inside your for loop. The code inside the loop is not actually doing anything. If you want to use this style of programming (known as functional programming), you may want to look at the `walk()` function inside the `purrr` package. It will be something also the lines of `purrr::walk(calculator$filename, function(x) ... )`.

Also, your output is currently not really an integer of length 17, but it is a variable `i` with the value 17. You can check it by executing `i` in your console. In R, `10L` is the integer `10`.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS thank you mate, I got there in the end with

```for (i in seq_along(exceptions$filename)){exceptions$filename[i] %>% image_read() %>% image_resize(.,exceptions$resizeval[i]) %>% image_write(.,exceptions$filename[i])}```